# Assembly: Combining three registers into one register

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32

I'm finding it hard to combine three registers each with two digit values into one register in the order of register one is the first two digits, register two is the next two digits, and register 3 the last two digits. It should look something like this r1 = 12, r2 = 34, r3 = 56, and r0 = 123456. Is there a way to write this using math operations?

This is way off but this is what i tried,

```
mov r1,#12
mov r2,#34
mov r3,#56
add r0, r2, r1, LSL #8
add r0, r3, r0, LSL #8
```

Resulting in `r0 = 795192`

[image: Debugger screenshot of register values]

Comment: 12 * 256 + 34 != 1234.

Comment: You want `r1*10000+r2*100+r3` or equivalently `((r1*100)+r2)*100+r3` You can turn that into shifts and adds if you like.

Comment: Are you sure you want to concatenate according to decimal digits, not bytes or **hex** digits like `0x12`, `0x34`, `0x56` into `0x123456`?  Decimal digits require base-10 math, not base-2 (shifts)

Comment: @Jester The Cortex-M family of microcontrollers has fast multipliers usually, so it's a good idea to just multiply.

Comment: If you want a decimal concatenation, you will have to do some math with numbers, there is no way around it. Simple shifts won't work. Shifting digits in base 10 numbers does **not** translate into shifting digits in base 2. It seems like you (op) are confusing binary and decimal operations. Your CPU doesn't have a decimal digit shift operation, only binary shift.

Answer (score 2):

Use a sequence of multiplications:

```
movs r1, #12          @ your numbers
movs r2, #34
movs r3, #56

movs r0, #100         @ for decimal shift
muls r1, r0           @     12 * 10 =   1200
adds r1, r2           @   1200 + 34 =   1234
muls r1, r0           @   1234 * 10 = 123400
adds r1, r3           @ 123400 + 56 = 123456
```

If you have an ARMv7-M capable CPU, you can improve the performance slightly using an `mla` instruction:

```
movs r1, #12          @ your numbers
movs r2, #34
movs r3, #56

movs r0, #100         @ for decimal shift
mla  r1, r1, r0, r2   @ 10 *   12 + 34 = 1234
mla  r1, r1, r0, r3   @ 10 * 1234 + 56 = 123456
```